GlobalContent.Provider React Native Expo
import React, {
    useState,
    useEffect,
    ReactNode,
    createContext,
    useContext,
} from 'react';
import { getCurrentUser } from '@/lib/appwrite';

// Define the props for the GlobalProvider component
interface GlobalProviderProps {
    children: ReactNode;
}

interface GlobalContextType {
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
    setIsLoggedIn: (value: boolean) => void;
    user: any;
    setUser: (user: any) => void;
    isLoading: boolean;
}

// Create the context with a default value
export const GlobalContext = createContext<GlobalContextType | undefined>(
    undefined
);

// Custom hook to use the GlobalContext
export const useGlobalContext = (): GlobalContextType => {
    const context = useContext(GlobalContext);
    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useGlobalContext must be used within a GlobalProvider');
    }
    return context;
};

// GlobalProvider component to provide the context to its children
export const GlobalProvider = ({
    children,
}: GlobalProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
    const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
    const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        getCurrentUser()
            .then((res) => {
                if (res) {
                    setIsLoggedIn(true);
                    setUser(res);
                } else {
                    setIsLoggedIn(false);
                }
                setIsLoading(false);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
                setIsLoading(false); // Ensure loading state is updated even on error
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <GlobalContext.Provider
            value={{ isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn, user, setUser, isLoading }}
        >
            {children}
        </GlobalContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default GlobalProvider;

Runtime error:

SyntaxError: /Users/pieczasz/Developer/Code/vodkie-app/src/context/GlobalProvider.ts: Unexpected token, expected "," (62:16)

Type error:

Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement<any, any>': type, props, keyts(2739)
Cannot find namespace 'GlobalContext'.ts(2503)

Please help me with this issue i want provider to work so everyone who have session is automatically redirect to /explore

For sure, you are coming from the JS Mastery video on React Native. I encountered the same problem. ChatGPT didn’t help, but I finally managed to find a really simple solution: change the file type. Instead of .ts, I changed it to .tsx, and it worked!
